# Update Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 from 4.1.1 to Latest (Rooted)

Tags: updates, rooting, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 running a rooted version of firmware version 4.1.1.  I would like to update my firmware to the latest version, while maintaining my root privileges.  How can I do this safely, and where can I find the latest rooted firmware for my device?

Comment: I would Recommend you XDA FORUM
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2581782

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am not necessarily looking for a custom firmware rom.  I'm simply hoping to upgrade to the latest stock firmware and re-root the tablet without wiping all my data with a factory reset.  The problem is that the Unroot guide on the forums has a deadlink to the "root_remover.zip".